# how to get multiple array elements after parsing and pass it to a data class

Tags: java, android, json

I couldn't get all array elemets after json pasrsing

***Fragment.java***

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView rv;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    MyTask myTask;
    ArrayList<GetData> al;

    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> 
    {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
        viewType) {
            View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, 
            parent, false);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int 
          position) {
            GetData g =al.get(position);
            holder.tv1.setText(g.getId());
            holder.tv2.setText(g.getRev());
            holder.tv3.setText(g.getChannels());
            holder.tv4.setText(g.getIpadd());
            holder.tv5.setText(g.getKey());
            holder.tv6.setText(g.getHupdate());
            holder.tv7.setText(g.getOldpass());
            holder.tv8.setText(g.getPass());
            holder.tv9.setText(g.getUname());
            holder.tv10.setText(g.getCid());
            holder.tv11.setText(g.getCdate());
            holder.tv12.setText(g.getNdevice().toString());
            holder.tv14.setText(g.getSsetup().toString());
            holder.tv15.setText(g.getType());
            holder.tv16.setText(g.getUpdate());

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return al.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5, tv6, tv7, tv8, tv9, 
             tv10, tv11, tv12, tv13, tv14, tv15, tv16;

            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tv1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id._id);
                tv2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rev);
                tv3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.channels);
                tv4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ipadd);
                tv5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.key);
                tv6 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hupdated);
                tv7 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.oldpass);
                tv8 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pass);
                tv9 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.uname);
                tv10 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comid);
                tv11= itemView.findViewById(R.id.createdDate);
                tv12 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dev);
                tv14 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set);
                tv15 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
                tv16 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.updated);

            }
        }
    }


    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void , String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("API","PreExecute" );
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Log.d("API", "BackGround");
            /* Establishing connection to url */
            try {
                URL u = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) 
                u.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic 
                b3NpOkF1ZyMyMDE4");
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                con.setRequestProperty("osi", "Aug#2018");
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);

                String s = br.readLine();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
                while (s !=null){
                    sb.append(s);
                    s = br.readLine();
                }
                return sb.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Kiran", "URL exception");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Kiran", "IO exception");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values){
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Log.d("API", "OnProgress");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            Log.d("API", "response: " +s);
            if(s == null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No response from url", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            /* Parsing Code*/
            else {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
                    String id = obj.getString("_id");
                    String rev = obj.getString("_rev");
                    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("channels");
                    String channels = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        channels =arr.get(i).toString();
                    }
                    JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject("commander");
                    String ipadd = obj2.getString("ipAddress");
                    String key = obj2.getString("keychainID");
                    String hupdate = obj2.getString("lastUpdatedDate");
                    JSONArray arr2 = obj2.getJSONArray("oldPasswords");
                    String oldpass = null;
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length(); j++) {
                        oldpass= arr2.get(j).toString();
                        Log.d("Kiran", "----------------------");
                    }
                    String pass = obj2.getString("password");
                    String uname = obj2.getString("userName");
                    String cid = obj.getString("companyID");
                    String cdate = obj.getString("createdDate");
                    Boolean ndevice = obj.getBoolean("isAllowNewDevice");
                    Boolean ssetup = obj.getBoolean("isStoreSetup");
                    String type = obj.getString("type");
                    String update = obj.getString("updatedDate");

                    GetData g = new GetData(id, rev,channels, ipadd, key, 
                  hupdate, oldpass, pass, uname, cid, cdate, ndevice, ssetup, 
                    type, update);
                    al.add(g);
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public MyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        rv = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, 
        false);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        al = new ArrayList<GetData>();

        myTask =new MyTask();
        myTask.execute("http://mydev.objectsourceincapps.com:4984/costalerts/
      store_1000023");

        return v;
    }

}
```

***Data.java***

```
    public class GetData {

    private String id;
    private String rev;
    private String channels;
    private String ipadd;
    private String key;
    private String hupdate;
    private String oldpass;
    private String pass;
    private String uname;
    private String cid;
    private String cdate;
    private Boolean ndevice;
    private Boolean ssetup;
    private String type;
    private String update;

    public GetData(String id, String rev, String channels,  String ipadd, String key, String hupdate,String oldpass, String pass, String uname, String cid, String cdate, Boolean ndevice, Boolean ssetup, String type, String update) {
        this.id = id;
        this.rev = rev;
        this.channels = channels;
        this.ipadd = ipadd;
        this.key = key;
        this.hupdate = hupdate;
        this.oldpass = oldpass;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.uname = uname;
        this.cid = cid;
        this.cdate = cdate;
        this.ndevice = ndevice;
        this.ssetup = ssetup;
        this.type = type;
        this.update = update;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRev() {
        return rev;
    }

    public void setRev(String rev) {
        this.rev = rev;
    }

    public String getIpadd() {
        return ipadd;
    }

    public void setIpadd(String ipadd) {
        this.ipadd = ipadd;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getHupdate() {
        return hupdate;
    }

    public void setHupdate(String hupdate) {
        this.hupdate = hupdate;
    }

    public String getChannels() {
        return channels;
    }

    public void setChannels(String channels) {
        this.channels = channels;
    }

    public String getOldpass() {
        return oldpass;
    }

    public void setOldpass(String oldpass) {
        this.oldpass = oldpass;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getCid() {
        return cid;
    }

    public void setCid(String cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }

    public String getCdate() {
        return cdate;
    }

    public void setCdate(String cdate) {
        this.cdate = cdate;
    }

    public Boolean getNdevice() {
        return ndevice;
    }

    public void setNdevice(Boolean ndevice) {
        this.ndevice = ndevice;
    }
    public Boolean getSsetup() {
        return ssetup;
    }

    public void setSsetup(Boolean ssetup) {
        this.ssetup = ssetup;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getUpdate() {
        return update;
    }

    public void setUpdate(String update) {
        this.update = update;
    }
}
```

***Data to be parsed***

```
{
    "_id": "store_1000023",
    "_rev": "87-d1e87e9b6b350666bd19f5455553a16e4c241e07",
    "channels": [
        "1000023"
    ],
    "commander": {
        "ipAddress": "18.215.105.64",
        "keychainID": "6866A0A0_77E4_4B64_AAE3_7FEBDA0C8745",
        "lastUpdatedDate": "2019-05-20T14:29:45.220Z",
        "oldPasswords": [
            "Y2N8B7K",
            "h0Y7I2c",
            "P5q6N5r",
            "y0C6s7M",
            "O2G4u8q"
        ],
        "password": "O2G4u8q",
        "userName": "kwikrun"
    },
    "companyID": "1000023",
    "createdDate": "2018-12-29T08:01:52.248Z",
    "isAllowNewDevice": false,
    "isStoreSetup": true,
    "type": "stores",
    "updatedDate": "2019-05-21T09:25:22.314Z"
}
```

Comment: Hi, I highly recommend you to ask a specific question and then tell something about the code and not only paste it here and let us think about it. I think you problem is not to give back the parsed data but to notify the view and then display the data. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly create a Model Class like your JSON Fomat which willl be like:-

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GetData {

    /**
     * _id : store_1000023
     * _rev : 87-d1e87e9b6b350666bd19f5455553a16e4c241e07
     * channels : ["1000023"]
     * commander : {"ipAddress":"18.215.105.64","keychainID":"6866A0A0_77E4_4B64_AAE3_7FEBDA0C8745","lastUpdatedDate":"2019-05-20T14:29:45.220Z","oldPasswords":["Y2N8B7K","h0Y7I2c","P5q6N5r","y0C6s7M","O2G4u8q"],"password":"O2G4u8q","userName":"kwikrun"}
     * companyID : 1000023
     * createdDate : 2018-12-29T08:01:52.248Z
     * isAllowNewDevice : false
     * isStoreSetup : true
     * type : stores
     * updatedDate : 2019-05-21T09:25:22.314Z
     */

    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("_rev")
    private String rev;
    @SerializedName("commander")
    private CommanderBean commander;
    @SerializedName("companyID")
    private String companyID;
    @SerializedName("createdDate")
    private String createdDate;
    @SerializedName("isAllowNewDevice")
    private boolean isAllowNewDevice;
    @SerializedName("isStoreSetup")
    private boolean isStoreSetup;
    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("updatedDate")
    private String updatedDate;
    @SerializedName("channels")
    private ArrayList<String> channels;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRev() {
        return rev;
    }

    public void setRev(String rev) {
        this.rev = rev;
    }

    public CommanderBean getCommander() {
        return commander;
    }

    public void setCommander(CommanderBean commander) {
        this.commander = commander;
    }

    public String getCompanyID() {
        return companyID;
    }

    public void setCompanyID(String companyID) {
        this.companyID = companyID;
    }

    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public boolean isIsAllowNewDevice() {
        return isAllowNewDevice;
    }

    public void setIsAllowNewDevice(boolean isAllowNewDevice) {
        this.isAllowNewDevice = isAllowNewDevice;
    }

    public boolean isIsStoreSetup() {
        return isStoreSetup;
    }

    public void setIsStoreSetup(boolean isStoreSetup) {
        this.isStoreSetup = isStoreSetup;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(String updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getChannels() {
        return channels;
    }

    public void setChannels(ArrayList<String> channels) {
        this.channels = channels;
    }

    public static class CommanderBean {
        /**
         * ipAddress : 18.215.105.64
         * keychainID : 6866A0A0_77E4_4B64_AAE3_7FEBDA0C8745
         * lastUpdatedDate : 2019-05-20T14:29:45.220Z
         * oldPasswords : ["Y2N8B7K","h0Y7I2c","P5q6N5r","y0C6s7M","O2G4u8q"]
         * password : O2G4u8q
         * userName : kwikrun
         */

        @SerializedName("ipAddress")
        private String ipAddress;
        @SerializedName("keychainID")
        private String keychainID;
        @SerializedName("lastUpdatedDate")
        private String lastUpdatedDate;
        @SerializedName("password")
        private String password;
        @SerializedName("userName")
        private String userName;
        @SerializedName("oldPasswords")
        private ArrayList<String> oldPasswords;

        public String getIpAddress() {
            return ipAddress;
        }

        public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
            this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
        }

        public String getKeychainID() {
            return keychainID;
        }

        public void setKeychainID(String keychainID) {
            this.keychainID = keychainID;
        }

        public String getLastUpdatedDate() {
            return lastUpdatedDate;
        }

        public void setLastUpdatedDate(String lastUpdatedDate) {
            this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getOldPasswords() {
            return oldPasswords;
        }

        public void setOldPasswords(ArrayList<String> oldPasswords) {
            this.oldPasswords = oldPasswords;
        }
    }
}
```

After that include below line in your app build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

then in your onPostExecute method add below code:-

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s){
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Log.d("API", "response: " +s);
        if(s == null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No response from url", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        /* Parsing Code*/
        else {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                GetData itemModel = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), GetData.class); 
                al.add(itemModel);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @kirankumar Pleased to help.